# Server has failed and is disabled until timed retry

Tags: php

I'm using `Memcached` all seems working fine in my `localhost` webserver, but when I've uploaded my application to my pay webhosting (not my) I got this error:

> SERVER HAS FAILED AND IS DISABLED UNTIL TIMED RETRY

this happen on this line:

```
echo self::$_memcached->getResultMessage();
```

I've this class configuration:

```
function __construct()
{
    self::$_memcached = new Memcached();
    self::$_memcached->addServer(Config::DB_HOST, 11211);

    $file = 'config.php';

    include $file;
    $this->_config = $config;

    foreach($config as $item => $value)
    {
        if(!(bool) self::$_memcached->get($item))
        {
            self::$_memcached->add($item, $value);
            echo self::$_memcached->getResultMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

AS I said all working fine in my localhost,  so I guess is a problem of my hosting provider? I've enabled in cpanel memcache and memcached extension, but seems even display this error.

The value of `Config::DB_HOST` is `localhost`, and also I tried with `127.0.0.1`, same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP, Memcached works from command line but not from the web](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159415/php-memcached-works-from-command-line-but-not-from-the-web)

Answer (score -3):

This is generated by libmemcached library. I'm unable to confirm how pecl_memcached handles this error, but I imagine it would be treated as a standard connectivity error. This message would be issued when a connection exceeds time-out and/or retry limit. (see I/O Options)

Naturally, as this is a temporary issue, you would architect your PHP application to fall-over to the next cache server, or pull affected server out of server list.

Comment: I've already read exactly: http://serverfault.com/questions/470951/how-to-debug-memcached-server-has-failed-and-is-disabled-until-timed-retry-err
nice copy and paste eh? :)

Comment: yep it answers your question perfectly, I will just report a duplicate instead of trying to help

Comment: This is not a duplicate, 'cause this question missing on stackoverflow, and also in the post that I linked there is no solution or why this error is generated. That's why I asked the question here, for find any help.

Comment: Its a standard connectivity error, PHP can not connect to the memcache instance. All the information is in the error. Login to SHH and ensure the memcached daemon is running, if it is then you know the connection problem is probably a config error in your PHP script.

Comment: the host is not my, what I can do only is enable the extension memcached, that's it